# Splitting line and determining unique output using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, splitting, split-by-attribute

I am using ArcGIS Pro on a water main system.

I have water mains and water main valves and I am trying to split the main at the valves.

The problem I am having is which attribute becomes the unique value. 2 of the attributes I have on the water main feature is objectID and Cartegraph ID. When I split the main at the valve I want the unique values to be on the Cartegraph ID, but it is making it the ObjectID. So for example if I am splitting the water main with cartegraph ID 1, I want the two mains to have cartegraph ID 1 and 2 as the final output.  However, it is applying the unique value to the Object ID attribute, giving that attribute the unique values of 1 and 2.

How do I get it to assign the new value to cartegraph ID rather than object ID?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Don't use ArcGIS's unique ID as a unique ID for this reason. But you can preserve the original ObjectID, but adding another field, and calculating that field to have the value of ObjectID.

You could also calculate long-lat for your water main points, and then do a field calculate with the lat-lon value concatenated. That will give you a unique ID ('UID') for your mains. Then you can use your mains to split your pipes. Then for each 'end' of the line-segment, use spatial join to attach the UID for each of the mains to each end of the pipe. Since you are doing it twice, you'll have to do a Near to water-main, and then use Select feature to take the top two values from the Near table. The high value will become the A end to your pipe, and the lower value the B end of your pipe. Then add two columns: Main A, Main B, and calculate their values as the UID for each of the two nearest mains.